# What is the rank of an integer?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given an integer, e.g. $-4$, I can implement it as an equivalence class of ordered pairs of naturals as follows:

$$(-4)_{\mathbb{Z}} := \{(1_{\mathbb{N}},5_{\mathbb{N}}),(2_{\mathbb{N}},6_{\mathbb{N}}), \dots \}$$
where $(a,b)$ (with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$) is a representative of the integer $a-b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What is the rank of $-4$ as an integer? Is it $\omega$, or $\omega+1$?

(I don't really know much about this subject area, so apologies if I haven't phrased my question very well)

Comment: As in *your past question*, you **must first** know, and tell us, what does "the rank of a number" mean! Also, what does $\;-4=\{(1,5), (2,6),...\}\;$ can possibly mean... It seems to be you have very confusing and partial knowledge of some things and you can't either express them correctly or simply don't know what is going on.

Comment: @DonAntonio It's a few abuses of notation, but they're all fairly standard. I'll edit the question to make them a bit clearer.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I would add "ferocious" between your "few" and your "abuses" , in particular since this seems to be at least college or university level.

Comment: @DonAntonio I re-asked because I figured I hadn't successfully got my point across in the last question, it seemed easier to re-ask with a different example than continually edit (new to the site,apologies if that's not what you're meant to do).

Comment: @Sally What you did is fine with me, though some purists around here wouldn't like that. My problem is with undefined notions and symbols you're using. BTW, perhaps you should say whether Patrick guessed correctly what you *actually* meant.

Comment: I concur that @Sally should say whether I edited and/or answered the question correctly.

Comment: Yes, you interpreted as I intended. Thank-you for the answer. Apologies for the notation issues (I'll try my best to work on that). Also (just guessing that I've breached the norms of the site), would it normally be better to edit a question rather than re-post?

Comment: @Sally No, in my humble opinion. Some here say yes, but that way questions remain forgotten in the past. Better, if after some time *nobody answered*, delete that question and post a new, corrected one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you implement the ordered pair, and how you implement the natural number.

The usual implementations are:

- the Kuratowski definition of the ordered pair: $(a,b) = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$
- the definition of a natural as an ordinal: $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{0, 1\}, \dots$

The definition of the rank of a set is $$\mathrm{rk}(x) = \sup \{ \mathrm{rk}(y) + 1 : y \in x \}$$
with $\mathrm{rk}(\emptyset) = 0$.

Therefore the rank of $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ is $0 \in \mathrm{Ord}$; the rank of $1 \in \mathbb{N}$ is $1 \in \mathrm{Ord}$; and generally the rank of the natural $n$ is the ordinal $n$.

The rank of the ordered pair $(m, n)$ of naturals is therefore the rank of $\{ \{m\}, \{m,n\}\}$, which is the sup of $\mathrm{rk}(\{m\})+1$ and $\mathrm{rk}(\{m,n\})+1$, which is itself the sup of $m+2$ and $\max(m,n)+2$, which is $\max(m,n)+2$.

Therefore the rank of the equivalence class $[(m,n)]$ is the sup of $\max(m',n')+3$ over all $m',n'$ with $m+n' = m'+n$.

That's $\omega$, of course.

---

The intuition is that each ordered pair $(m,n)$ has finite rank, and we've just collected them all together, so the resulting set has rank $\omega$ for the same reason that the set $\mathbb{N}$ has rank $\omega$.

I'm told by a reliable source that the question of "what rank does this object have?" is not one that most mathematicians will find interesting, mainly because it's in general highly dependent on the implementations of the objects. Most mathematicians don't really care how the objects are implemented; only that they *can* be implemented.